# Choose any combination of $2, 3$, or $4$ letters out of these $7$; $a, b, c, d, e, f,$ and $g$. How many combinations are there?

Tags: combinatorics

> Choose any combination of $2, 3$, or $4$ letters out of these $7$; $a, b, c, d, e, f,$ and $g$. How many combinations are there?

I really don't know much about combinatorics or math really. I'm using this for writing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what $n\choose r$ means?

Comment: $7^2+7^3+7^4$ combinations.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Why is $\binom{n}{r}$ needed here?

Comment: @barakmanos Because order doesn't matter?

Comment: @barakmanos ${n\choose r}$ is used for combinations, not $n^r$...

Comment: @Lovsovs: Of course it doesn't. But the question doesn't restrict one occurrence of each letter either.

Comment: @barakmanos The question would need to clarify if repetition of letters is allowed.

Comment: @barakmanos Good point!

Comment: @GoodDeeds: My approach that a question needs to clarify if something is **not** allowed, but I guess that this is debatable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard notation used in counting problems like this one, and it called "$n$ choose $k$", or a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), and is written like this: $\binom{n}{k}$. It gives the number of ways in which to choose $k$ elements out of $n$, when order doesn't matter (for instance, it doesn't matter whether you first picked an $a$ and then a $b$, or if you picked $b$ first and then $a$).

So in your three problems you, you're looking for 
\begin{align}\binom{7}{2} &=21 \\ \binom{7}{3} &=35 \\ \binom{7}{4} &=35 \\ \end{align}

The above also assumes that any given letter can only be chosen one time.

If you, on the other hand, is looking for the number of ways of choosing the $k$ letters when you can choose each letter multiple times, you simply have $n^k$ ways of doing this (i.e., $7^2, 7^3,7^4$) since you have a choice between $7$ letters each time you're picking one.

Comment: The above also assumes that the order of the letters is not important.

Comment: @barakmanos Yes, I wrote that.

Comment: I'm reading the bottom line, starting with "The above assumes", and I don't quite see it there...

Comment: @barakmanos I wrote "when order doesn't matter". To clarify, I added an "also".

Answer (score 0):

There are $8$ things to pick out of, and if you pick $k$ things out of $n$, you can do this in ${n\choose k}$ different ways, where

$${n\choose k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1}$$

So, if you are picking $2$ things out of $8$, you can do that in

$$\frac{8\cdot 7}{2\cdot 1} = 28$$ different ways. You can similarly calculate how many ways you can pick $3$ and $4$ objects, then sum the numbers together.

Comment: The question doesn't restrict one occurrence of each letter.

Comment: @barakmanos The question says "combination"...

Comment: I understand, but given the context of this question, I don't think that it is distinguishable from *permutation* (i.e., the OP doesn't sound like he or she are even aware of the difference between these two terms).

Comment: OK, you may be right. I don't know. My answer is an answer to what the question is asking now, even though I admit it may not be what OP *wanted* to ask. If he clarifies the question, I will change my answer.

Comment: I think that unless explicitly stated, there is no restriction on the number of occurrences of each letter (and as a "byproduct" of that, also on the order of the letters). But I guess that it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @barakmanos And I don't think so because the question asks about combinations, and combinations have a restriction on the number of occurunces built into their definition. But anyway, this debat is pointless if OP doesn't explain what they wanted.

Comment: I agree on that.